# How to show textinput box above the Keyboard while entering the input in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I am using TextField widget in my project. I need to show the InputBox above the keyboard if the user clicks and start typing on the  TextField, WhatsApp has this functionality in Landscape mode:
[image]

I need this functionality in my flutter application too, any little help will be very welcome, Thank you in advance.

Issue updated it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993189/fullscreen-keyboard-when-keyboard-is-open-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: Thank you, I updated it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993189/fullscreen-keyboard-when-keyboard-is-open-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 0):

below code will help you

```
import 'package:chat_system_flutter/utils/common_logic.dart';
import 'package:chat_system_flutter/utils/common_string.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, bool isKeyboardVisible) {
        if (isKeyboardVisible) {
          // blok of code
        }
        return Obx(
          () => Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            body: body(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget body() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        hideKeyboard(context);
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                   //message listview
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 10,
                vertical: 0,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageController,
                      autocorrect: true,
                      enableSuggestions: true,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        // block of code
                      },
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: typeYourMsgStr,
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                        ),
                        border: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                      /*    onSubmitted: (_) {
                              sendMsg();
                            },*/
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      // send message
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_upward,
                        color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

output

[image: output like]

Comment: Thank you, I updated it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993189/fullscreen-keyboard-when-keyboard-is-open-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: you use whole code that i send ?

Comment: try once run in another device so get the proper issue

Comment: No I am using a plugin as I said in the updated issue

Comment: okay, but you don't need to include a plugin for this. without plugin you can fix it by wrapping some specific widget

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a padding in your main Container which contains your TextField like this:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 10,
            right: 10,
            left: 10,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 10,
          ),
```

What *MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom* does is that it takes the height of onscreen keyboard and adds it to padding whenever the keyboard appears on the screen. This makes your TextField to move 10 pixels above your keyboard (that's because we added 10 to bottom padding separately).

Another Widget that would help with scrolling is wrapping your main widget with a SingleChildScrollView.

Feel free to clear up any confusions in the comments :)

Comment: Thank you, I updated it, Now there is a new issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993189/fullscreen-keyboard-when-keyboard-is-open-in-landscape-mode)